# Why the block author is always `Alice`?

Tags: aura, session

[image]

I implemented my own staking pallet, which implemented the `SessionManager`. And I pass it to `pallet_session::Config`.

I can confirm the session keys are set correctly.

If I stop the `Alice` node, then the `Bob` start to produce blocks.

Why `Alice` always get the authority to produce block?

Code: https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0/blob/xavier/staking/pallet/staking/src/lib.rs

Comment: There's not enough information here for people to help. Have you confirmed that the output of `new_session` for your pallet is correct? Have you checked the validators are correct? You can get them from a running chain via the explorer: Chain State > session > validators.

Comment: Yes, they are correct. As I said if I stop `Alice` node, then `Bob` starts to produce blocks.  Which means the keys are correct.

Comment: What about the set of authorities used by aura? If the set of authorities from aura is `[Alice, Bob]`, then both should be producing blocks equally, so there is more than likely an issue somewhere between your pallet and the set of aura authorities.

Comment: I think they are correct. I put the code link in the question. Maybe you could find some issues?

Comment: I read through the code in the link, and everything looks correct there. Are you making sure to wait 2 sessions before expecting a new set of authorities to take effect? You can check aura authorities on a running chain by Chain State > aura > authorities. If the aura authorities are correct (alice + bob) and bob can author blocks only when alice disconnects, that would imply an issue within / with aura setup or keys somehow.

Comment: I posted a stupid answer. Maybe you could find out something from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [slot duration](https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0/blob/5e760e0a1766ee30ba51540ec5f32a1ee63fb1f7/core/primitives/src/lib.rs#L69) in your runtime is wrong:

```
pub const MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK: u64 = 6_000;
pub const SLOT_DURATION: u64 = MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK;
```

You are running a parachain that can only produce a block every 12 seconds. You have set your slot time to 6 seconds. That means that you always skip `Bob`. Always when it is the turn of `Bob`, there is "no slot" in the relay chain to build a parachain block.

So, the solution is to set the following as slot duration:

```
pub const MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK: u64 = 12_000;
```